# ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/card/typings/card-module.d.ts(12,55)

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working with angular project as well as i using `visual studio code` as the  text editor. There is an error occurred when I trying to open the project by using `npm-start`. The error as following manner.

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/card/typings/card-module.d.ts(12,55): error TS1183: An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.node_modules/@angular/material/card/typings/card-module.d.ts(20,55): error TS1183: An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Then what should I do for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the angular material is not installed,try **npm install** and see if it's fixed
if not try to add angular material to your project using:

> npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations

you can see next steps [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)